# In a group, is it hard to calculate the base $g$ given $g^a$ and $a$?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, finite-field, group-theory

Discrete logarithm, that is: calculate $a$ given $g$ and $g^a$, is assumed to be a hard problem in some groups.

Is it also hard to calculate $g$ given $g^a$ and $a$?

Answer (score 12):

It depends. *If the order $m$ of $g$'s group is known* and *$a$ has an inverse modulo $m$* (which is the case if and only if $a$ is coprime to $m$), then it is easy: Calculate the inverse $b:=a^{-1}\bmod m$ (for instance, using the Euclidean algorithm), and compute the power $(g^a)^b$. By Lagrange's theorem, this equals $g$.

However, there are cases for which it's hard: for example, when $n=pq$ is the product of two unknown primes $p,q$ and $g\in\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$, then the task is equivalent to decrypting the RSA ciphertext $g^a$ with respect to the public key $(n,a)$, which is generally assumed to be hard.

Comment: in case of RSA, it's know that in general there is no generator, $(\mathbb{Z}/n.\mathbb{Z})^*$ is not a cyclic group.

Comment: is it mean that in cyclic group it can be calculated by finding inverse of a, but in general like RSA encryption it is not true.

Comment: No, it can be calculated in any group whose order is known (actually, even the group's exponent is sufficient). Lagrange's theorem guarantees that in *any* group of order $m$, the congruence $ab\equiv1\pmod m$ implies $(g^a)^b=1$. The group need not be cyclic, neither is $g$ required to generate the whole group.

Comment: Even if the "whole group" is not cyclic, you are actually working in the cyclic subgroup generated by $g$, so the distinction is irrelevant.

Comment: Also, of course $a^{-1}\bmod m$ does not always exist.

Comment: The question about "a generator" is misleading, because it is wrong [terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group). In general, there is a *generating set* and its elements are called *generators* - no signular. Elements can *generate* a group. And along this line a single element can *generate* a (sub)group, which implies that the set contains one element and the generated group is cyclic. But that doesn't mean there is **a generator** .

Comment: @tylo: +1. I totally agree. In crypto, we are generally in presence of commutative free groups, and as I mentioned above, there is no generator, for RSA case it's absurde to talk about GENERATORS. But each element of the group can be generated as a product of generators of its subgroups.

Answer (score -1):

If you know $a$, you also know $\frac{1}{a}$ then $g=(g^a)^{\frac{1}{a}}$.

Now, answering the question for solving $X^r - a = 0$, when $r \mid (p-1)$. If my analysis is correct, if $r\mid (p-1)$, the square root algorithm can easily be adapted depending on the form of prime $p$.

- If $p=2rq + 2r -1$, this is a deterministic case: let $$y_0=a^{\frac{p+1}{2 \times r}} \quad \Longrightarrow \quad y_0^r=\left(\frac{a}{p}\right) \times a$$

Then if $a \in QR(p)$, a particular solution is $y_0=a^{\frac{p+1}{2 \times r}}$ otherwise there is no solution!

- If $p$ in other form: a particular solution can be calculated by a probabilistic algorithm, and is too complicated to expose here.

By the way, when a particular solution is calculated, all the $r$ roots are conjugate to each other, and are of the form $y_i =\mu_i \times y_0 \;\cdots \; \mu_i$ is one of the $r$ $r$th roots of Unity.

I emphasize that the cryptographic protocol should appropriately specify the conditions for the uniqueness in the solution of a given protocol, and in this case, we can use abusive notation like $\frac{1}{a}$.

And there should always be a method for selecting the appropriate solution.
The algorithm I mentioned here can be proved with the background given in Henri Cohen's book, a former professor in the Maths Dpt of BDX.

Comment: g is also a primitive elevent: obvious !

Comment: correct. but in modulo arithmetic is it correct?

Comment: @Aria: when we talk about a generator, generally it's a element of maximal order in a group. In the case of a finite field the multiplicative group is cyclic, and hence there is generators. A finite field can be prime (in which case modular arithmetic holds) or an extension of a finite degre of a prime field.

Comment: What's $1/a$?$\;\;$

Comment: @fkraiem: It's the multiplicative inverse of $a$ modulo the order of the group (which would be $p-1$ if we're working in the group $Z_p^*$)

Comment: @poncho I was of course being sarcastic. ;) The answer seems to assume that $1/a$ exists, which is not necessarily the case.

Comment: @fkraiem: if $1/a$ doesn't exist (that is, if $a$ and the group order $q$ are not relatively prime), then $g$ won't be uniquely determinable (if one exists, there might not); however it wouldn't be difficult to find a $g$ that does work (assuming, of course, that such a $g$ exists)

Comment: @poncho Not sure why you are telling me this, of course I know it. This should be in an answer.

Comment: @fkraiem: If we believe your post, it would be impossible to compute the square root in the multiplicative groupe of a finite field. Before beiing Scarcastic, try beforehand to understand the lecture of Professor Henri COHEN and the course in computational Agebraic Number Theory. Probably since the retirement of Henri COHEN, the mathematical level of some student is decreasing.

Comment: @RobertNACIRI Excuse me? Are you saying that an element of a finite field $K$ always has a square root in $K$?

Comment: And that's not even the matter. You are given two integers $a$ and $m$, there is no reason to assume that $a$ is relatively prime with $m$. The rest of your message is a ridiculous ad hominem.

Comment: @fkraiem, I only have to redirect you again to the initial question. Given $g^a$, and $a$, Compute g. As Poncho observe it, there is always a method to find g !
The rest is not important. 
I discuss only with no scarcastic people, who really want to exchange and share Knowledge. Bye!

Comment: The question does not state that $a$ is relatively prime with the order of $g$.  If you think it does, that's your problem. Ah, the tragedy of old age...

Comment: And by the way, you mention poncho's message but you apparently don't understand it. He said that if $a$ is not relatively prime with $n$, which is of course possible, then $g$ is not uniquely determined by $a$ and $g^a$. And, since you mention square roots, I'll remind you that in general an element in a field has two square roots (if it has square roots at all of course).

Comment: Game Over ! 
My final advice: Read H. Cohen's book !
And also take a look to the archive (2002 ...? ) of Bdx Crypto & NT laboratory (I don't remember details. Tragedy of age of course).

Comment: @RobertNACIRI you are wrong, please read carefully the discussion.

Comment: @Hyperflame, Thank you for your interest. However about this thread, I tried to give general orientation to help on possible solutions, without developping more.
Because it depend on a lot of others conditions. For exemple if the prime p is a appropriate form, and with the help of Legendre symbol of g, we could allways have a unique determination.
If the question is only in the field of my skill, I'll happy to answer.

Comment: @Hyperflame, additionnal remark: If you know the rabin cryptosystem, with a public exponent e=2. You certainly noticed the abuse notation commonly accepted, that the secret exponent is $d=\frac{1}{2} \; mod \; \lambda(n)$. With additionnal assumption on p and q, allow to exhibit a unique solution.
I don't give detail you can easilly find over the web.

Comment: @RobertNACIRI 1/2 never exists mod $\lambda(pq)$. There's no such term as "secret exponent" in Rabin's cryptosystem. You are writing complete nonsense. The unanswered part of the question is how to extract $r$-roots modulo prime $p$, given that $r$ divides $p - 1$, for arbitrary $r$. If it is "in the field of your skill", then answer it. Otherwise this is just a flood that misleads the readers of this topic.

Comment: @Hyperflame 1- Complete your profile without anonymity in order to avoid concealment,
2- OK, I understand you're right. I don't remember exactly the expression with $\lambda$.
I read it in the preliminary draft ISO/IEC 9796 at the end of the $80^{ies}$ and that everyone know why it was abandonned just after being be published few years after.
3- If I mentioned the Rabin system, it was just to give an exemple of the unique determination of a signature when the public exponenent is e=2.
decryption can be processed by either CRT or regular exponentiation algorithm and formulas exists.

Comment: @Hyperflame: Suite
Take a look over the web to this system and the use of Blum integers to learn how the system work.
4- You ask how to extract r-root if r | p-1. If you know Galois theory, you can transform the problem to extract the r-root of Unity, and by multiplying with on particular solution, you obtain all the others.
if a is a r-power, x^r-a=0 has r-solution is a finite field, and all the solutions are conjugate with each 
5- If you want to solve over the ring $(Z/p_1....p_k.Z)^*$, they  are $r^k$ solutions.
Hope this help your understanding.

Comment: @RobertNACIRI that's right. The last thing is how to solve x^r-a=0?

Comment: @Hyperflame: Solving $X^r - a = 0$ ? Ah! That's the QUESTION.
I edited my previous answer.